# Uma Activity para cada ação ou várias ações na mesma Activity?

Tags: android

Estou com dúvidas de como utilizar a Activity do Android.

Uso como um *controller*, passando tudo que será gerenciado do *model*, ou faço um para cada "tela"?

Exemplo: Tenho a tela inicial que escolhe a ação, Uma Tela que Cria Evento, Uma tela que lista Eventos, Uma tela que mostra evento especifico.

Crio, então um Activity para cada, ou faço com que uma (EventoActivity) que controla todas as requisições ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O ideal é ter uma activity para cada uma de suas telas.

Você pode ver mais sobre o funcionamento das activitys na [documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

Não se esqueça de declarar as activitys no `AndroidManifest.xml`